# Parse Integer From Text File Error With Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function that is able to take a text file and separate each line into individual strings and adds them to an array, after which I will take the strings and convert the numbers into Integers or Doubles. However, it keeps returning a NumberFormatException whenever I try to do Integer.parseInt() on the first string in the array, which is always an integer.

This code is a simplified version of what I am attempting to do:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File file = new File("preprocessed_data.txt");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                if (line.length() != 0) {

                    // Splitting each line into an array of Strings
                    String[] strings = line.split("\\s+");

                    // Trying to convert the first String into an Integer
                    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strings[0]));

                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is the text file which I am trying to process:

> 11259   8111    +2    14   5.9   5.1  2.0 662.8449  1324.6825 1324.6817 0.0008   1     √     CDFEK($1)  KLTK($1)  [A1:5  P215:218]
>
> 10365   4551    +2    28  11.0   9.0  1.7 643.3196  1285.6320
>   1285.6245 0.0075   1     √     CDFEK($1)  K($1)FR  [A1:5  P311:313]
>
> 16242   4175    +3    23  13.4   7.3  1.6 546.6142  1637.8280
>   1637.8316 -0.0035   3     √     CDFEK($1)K  K($1)GDKAR  [A1:6  O448:453]
>
> 27030  24226    +3    16   5.4   6.4  1.7 893.4433  2678.3153
>   2678.3178 -0.0024   2     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  IK($1)DNNMR + OxiM(22) 27031  25071    +3    10   4.8   5.1  2.6 893.4530  2678.3445
>   2678.3178 0.0267   2     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  IK($1)DNNMR + OxiM(22) [A6:19  D503:509]
>
> 25104  18270    +3    19   6.8   5.8  1.7 805.7773  2415.3173
>   2415.2965 0.0207   2     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  LRNLK($1)  [A6:19  I271:275  A6:19  I329:333  A6:19  I369:373]
>
> 27761  30048    +3    37   6.0   6.5  1.7 959.4729  2876.4041
>   2876.3883 0.0158   1     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  ELNEQAGESK($1)  [A6:19  I469:478]
>
> 26769  27493    +3    17  13.0   6.4  1.3 883.4568  2648.3560
>   2648.3541 0.0019   1     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  KPLDFEK($1) 26781  28982    +3    15   9.4   6.6  1.6 883.4586  2648.3611 2648.3541
>   0.0070   1     √     KSFCAWLNVPNGNK($1)  KPLDFEK($1)  [A6:19  K1379:1385]

And this is the error which I keep getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "﻿11259"
>     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>     at com.company.test.main(test.java:25)

Comment: Does the debugger show any dodgy characters in the string you're trying to parse?

Comment: Your code works for me with exactly this file content. Seems like you have some characters at the begining of the line indeed.

Comment: It will be helpful if you add this line of code just prior to the Integer.parseInt() line;   IntStream.range(0, strings[0].length()).forEach(i -> System.out.println(strings[0].getBytes()[i]));;
This will print the byte value of each character, and might shed some insight to why the parsing is failing.  If any value is not between 48 and 57 you have a problem.

Comment: @IanMc Thanks, I tried that and it was indeed printing out numbers outside of that range. I figured out while trying to copy the text into a different file, that the problem was that the text file was being encoded as UTF-8 and when I changed it to ANSI when saving the file it worked. If you don't mind, could you explain why, when I put that code in, the value should be between 48 and 57, what does it mean if it is out of that range?

Comment: There are standard ASCII codes for all characters. 
 The numbers 0-9 have ASCII codes 48-57. 
 https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file I was attempting to process was encoded with UTF-8, and once I switched it to ANSI it removed the invisible characters in the beginning of the file and the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like invisible characters, because your code works for me.

I would highly recommend opening the file in an editor like the notepad.exe on windows and make sure, that there are no invisible characters.